# Получить информацию по pid

Tags: ос, linux

Собственно, известен pid процесса, как можно узнать, какую память он использует и какая нагрузка на процессор? А если можно получить что-то больше, я не откажусь. :)

Comment: Для начала почитайте `man 5 proc` (куча полезной информации).

Если что-то поближе к юзеру, то см. утилиты `top` и `lsof`.

Comment: Спасибо, но что то у меня не выходит хоть что то получить :(
dev@www-z:/proc/18572$ ls
attr    clear_refs       cpuset   exe     io        maps       mounts      numa_maps  pagemap      sched      stack  status   wchan
auxv    cmdline          cwd      fd      limits    mem        mountstats  oom_adj    personality  sessionid  stat   syscall
cgroup  coredump_filter  environ  fdinfo  loginuid  mountinfo  net         oom_score  root         smaps      statm  task
dev@www-z:/proc/18572$ cd /stat
-bash: cd: /stat: No such file or directory
dev@www-z:/proc/18572$

Comment: @wwwplaton: `cd /stat` будет пытаться найти `stat` директорию в корне (`/` директория), что не верно два раза: 1. Нужно смотреть на `/proc/18572/stat` (то есть на `stat`, который в текущей директории, а не в корне) 2. `stat` это не директория. Содержимое можно посмотреть используя `cat stat` ([man 5 proc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) описывает формат). Вот [кроссплатформенное решение `procinfo.py` на Питоне, используя psutil модуль](https://gist.github.com/zed/09352b5d0dfd232d4bc8).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать `ps`, чтобы узнать потребление процессора, памяти процессом по его pid:

```
$ ps -p 18572 -o %cpu,%me
```

На Linux, ps может читать из `/proc/18572/stat`, чтобы получить эту информацию.